# Why Flag to close is "Disputed" even if question closed for the same reason afterwards?

Tags: support, specific-question, disputed-flags

I recently flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715231/should-i-be-using-ruby-on-rails) question for being primarily opinion-based. Why did my flag get disputed and not marked as helpful since it was put on hold for primarily opinion-based?

[image: disputed flag]

Comment: [This is why.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13803104) Triage voted it "looks okay" and I bet if you check the time the "disputed" was set, it will be the time of the last review. Triage reviews disputes flags, sadly.

Comment: @Kendra How were you able to find the Triage record of it? So basically it got approved my Triage then it got put on hold afterwards?

Comment: As JAL edited into their answer, through the question timeline. You can also find the finished close vote review that way as well. The question was cleared through Triage, yes, and _then_ the question was closed. Your flag was an unfortunate victim of bad reviewers.

Comment: @Kendra Cool thanks. At least it got handled correctly in the end.

Comment: The post is still advertising the tour site. Any enthusiasm for deleting it prior to it being deleted?

Answer (score 4):

The flag was disputed because three users clicked "Looks OK" in the [Triage review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13803104) (completing the review) where it had gathered two close votes.

It must have gotten a third close vote some time afterwards.  When it [entered the close vote queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/13803816), two users voted to close the question, completing the review.

This information was found by looking at the question's [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39715231/timeline).

Comment: Can we get a mod to poke these reviewers with a stick to see if they say "ow"? That's an obviously off-topic question.

Comment: *sharpens his poking stick*

Comment: Is the timeline link something that shows up at a certain rep level?

Comment: @BSMP No, any rep level can access it I believe.  I constructed this link manually, it doesn't show up anywhere.

Comment: @Shog9 darn, why you must do it just as I casted a flag :/